# jquery validate either checkbox or input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I had a form that can send message and user need to select group from checkbox or manual input the group name. Now i want validate this form, if user not check any checkbox or insert any value in text field this form cannot sumbit.

Below is my form and here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ruslyrossi/SNb2V/) (already validate textarea).

```
<form action="" method="post" name="myform" id="myform">

   <input type="checkbox" name="group_list[]" value="1" />Group 1<br />
   <input type="checkbox" name="group_list[]" value="1" />Group 1<br />
   <input type="checkbox" name="group_list[]" value="1" />Group 1<br />
   <input type="checkbox" name="group_list[]" value="1" />Group 1<br />

   <input type="text" name="manual_group" value="" placeholder="Group Name" /><br />

   <textarea name="message" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea> <br />

   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Message" />

</form>
```

User need to check one of checkbox or insert group name before submit.So the question is how to create condition for this rule?

*Remember this form still can submit if i not check one of the checkbox but key-in some name in `manual_group` , this form also can sumbit if i not key-in any name but check for checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by setting a rule on the textbox that it is required only if none of the checkboxes are checked.  This uses the type of [required specification that takes a function as a parameter](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/required#dependency-callback).

```
rules: {
    manual_group: {
        required: function () {
            return $('[name=group_list\\[\\]]:checked').length === 0;
        }
    }
}
```

The other thing you need to do is force a re-validation when either the checkboxes or the textbox are changed.  I have done it like this,

```
$('form input').on('click focusin focusout keyup', function () {
    $('form').validate().form();
});
```

The full script is below, [and in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wJnFn/)

```
$(function () {

    $("form").validate({
        rules: {
            manual_group: {
                required: function () {
                    return $('[name=group_list\\[\\]]:checked').length === 0;
                }
            }
        },
        messages: {
            manual_group: "Please check a checkbox or fill in this field"
        },
        submitHandler: function () {
            alert('form ok');
        }
    });


    $('form input').on('click focusin focusout keyup', function () {
        $('form').validate().form();
    });
});
```

Comment: FYI:  Simply `$('form').valid()` in place of `$('form').validate().form()` will work as well.

Answer (score 0):

with reference to your Fiddle

you can add it in the same way just like the validation you'hv added for message

e.g.

```
"group_list[]": {required:true}...
```

Comment: yes but this form cannot submit if i not check one of the checkbox..i want this form still can submit if user not check any checkbox but keyin some name in manual_group ..

Answer (score 0):

May be this will work

```
 $("#submit").click(function(){
        if($('#myform input:checked').length >= 1 || $("#manual_group").val() !=""){
           return true  ;
        }
       return false;   
    }
```